# Can't acess dynamic element on webpage

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, dynamic

I can't acess a textbox on a webpage box , it's a dynamic element. I've tried to filter it by many attributes on the xpath but it seems that the number that changes on the id and name is the only unique part of the element's xpath. All the filters I try show at least 3 element. I've been trying for 2 days, really need some help here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
def click_btn(submit_xpath): #clicks on button
    submit_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(submit_xpath)
    submit_box.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(7)
    return

#sends text to text box
def send_text_to_box(box_xpath, text):
    box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(box_xpath)
    box.send_keys(text)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    return

descr = 'Can't send this text'
send_text_to_box('//*[@id="textfield-1285-inputEl"]', descr)' #the number         
#here is the changeable part on the xpath
```

:[image: here is part the html of the page, and the text box's I wan't is highlighted]

---

edit: it worked now with the following xpath //input[contains(@id, 'textfield') and contains(@aria-readonly, 'false') and contains (@class, 'x-form-invalid-field-default')] . Hopefully I found something specific on this element:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use partial string to find the element instead of an exact match. That is, in place of 
`send_text_to_box('//*[@id="textfield-1285-inputEl"]', descr)'` please try `send_text_to_box('//*[contains(@id,"inputEl")]', descr)'`

In case if there are multiple elements that have string 'inputE1' in id, you should look for something else that remains constant(some other property may be). Else, try finding some other element and then traverse to the required input.

Comment: I've tried to find unique attributes to this element many times and didn't work. I'll search about 'transversing', thank you :)

Comment: Could do it by using send_text_to_box("//input[contains(@id, 'textfield') and contains(@aria-readonly, 'false') and contains (@class, 'x-form-invalid-field-default')]", descr). Many, thanks